# Look over associative array of values while creating test data for new wordpress plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

While building a WordPress plugin, during my activation hook, I am calling the following method to build test data in my new database table. I'm trying to loop over the values to add the data:

```
public static function installData()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $authorID = (get_current_user_id()) ? get_current_user_id() : '1';
        $demoData = [
            0 => [
                'id' => '122',
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'url' => 'https://www.efsnetworks.com',
                'image' => 'http://www.news.ucsb.edu/sites/www.news.ucsb.edu/files/styles/article_horizontal/public/images/2018/Cubic%20salt%20crystal%20aggregate.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2016-09-23 21:57:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => '123',
                'title' => 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud',
                'url' => 'https://www.google.com',
                'image' => 'https://cdn.britannica.com/s:500x350/66/143166-049-4900844D.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2017-07-23 22:02:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ],
            2 => [
                'id' => '124',
                'title' => 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate',
                'url' => 'https://www.disruptivetechnology.com',
                'image' => 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/1/13/Rock_crystal.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2018-12-23 22:03:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ]
        ];
        $table_name = $wpdb->wpAdvertisementAds;

        foreach ($demoData as $index=>$values) {
            foreach ($values as $key=>$value) {
                $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name,
                    [ $key => $value]
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

When this runs, I see that the data is adding a new row due to the `$wpdb-insert` clause inside the nested `foreach`. Yet when I move that outside into the first `foreach`, data does not get added. I eventually have to rewrite it to the following which works:

```
public static function installData()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $authorID = (get_current_user_id()) ? get_current_user_id() : '1';
        $table_name = $wpdb->wpAdvertisementAds;

        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            [
                'id' => '122',
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'url' => 'https://www.efsnetworks.com',
                'image' => 'http://www.news.ucsb.edu/sites/www.news.ucsb.edu/files/styles/article_horizontal/public/images/2018/Cubic%20salt%20crystal%20aggregate.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2016-09-23 21:57:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ]
        );
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            [
                'id' => '123',
                'title' => 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud',
                'url' => 'https://www.google.com',
                'image' => 'https://cdn.britannica.com/s:500x350/66/143166-049-4900844D.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2017-07-23 22:02:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ]
        );
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            [
                'id' => '124',
                'title' => 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate',
                'url' => 'https://www.disruptivetechnology.com',
                'image' => 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/1/13/Rock_crystal.jpg',
                'type' => 'small-block',
                'authorID' => $authorID,
                'dateCreated' => '2018-12-23 22:03:34',
                'lastUpdate' => null,
                'publishStatus' => '0'
            ]
        );
    }
```

Do you have any tips to making this method work with a simple `foreach` command of my data. This way I could move the dataset outside the php and into a json file or whatever file source (not related but could be used for future use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want the inner `foreach` loop. Your code should be:

```
foreach ($demoData as $value) {
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        $value
    );
}
```

Comment: very cool - thank you. i wasn't understanding the point where my array is already in the preferred format, so i can just put in `$value` into the insert. thanks!